# Breakup of VF Page URL

Tags: visualforce

I want to understand the elements in URL when I click on preview of VF page. The URL that I have is:

```
https://my-domain-dev-ed--my-namespace.na34.visual.force.com/apex/TestPage
```

My namespaced org has namespace : `my_namespace`

and `my-domain-dev-ed` is my domain name. I want to understand what is the text after '--' in the above URL. Is it the namespace where '_' is replaced by '-'? And is this always done when namespace contains an underscore? Also, what are other consideration while using parsing an URL to get certain values? I could not find proper documentation for this.

The thing that I want to do here originally is to get domain name dynamically from controller and for that I am using `URL.SubstringBefore(separator)` where `URL = 'https://my-domain-dev-ed--my-namespace.na34.visual.force.com/apex/TestPage'` and `separator = '--' + namespace;`, where `namespace` is returned from some static variable. But this is failing because the value of namespace returned is different from the value in URL.

Answer (score 2):

### URL Type

**Login**

```
https://<subdomain>.my.​salesforce.com
```

**Application page or tab**

```
https://<subdomain>.my.​salesforce.com​/<pageID>
```

**Visualforce page with no namespace**

```
https://<subdomain>--c.​<instance>.visual.​force.com​/apex​/<pagename>
```

**Visualforce page with namespace**

`https://<subdomain>--​<yournamespace>.​<instance>.visual.force.com​/apex/​`

> If you implement My Domain in a sandbox environment, the URL format is `https://<subdomain>--<sandboxname>.<instance>.my.salesforce.com`. Because you can’t have namespaces in a sandbox environment, the format of all Visualforce page URLs in a sandbox is `https://<subdomain>--<sandboxname>--c.<instance>.visual.force.com/apex/<pagename>`.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/domain_name_app_url_changes.htm)

**Below code will give you the NamespacePrefix of your Organization**

```
String NamespacePrefix = [SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization].NamespacePrefix;
System.debug('** ' + NamespacePrefix );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. As per this the URL should have been `https://my-domain-dev-ed--my_namespace.na34.visual.force.com/apex/TestPage`  as namespace is 'my_namespace', but why my URL is constructed as `https://my-domain-dev-ed--my-namespace.na34.visual.force.com/apex/TestPage
`

Comment: @Sarang  If you have given my_namespace then it display as my-namespace in Url. I have no idea reason behind this  why salesforce convert '_' with '-' in Url .

Comment: @Sarang String NamespacePrefix = [SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization].NamespacePrefix;  give you NamespacePrefix for you .

Comment: I already have namespace prefix, the problem is that the '_' in the namespace is replaced with '-' while referred from URL. I can handle this but just wanted to know if salesforce has this as standard behaviour.